# How to close windows in VBA Editor with VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file excel and I ' d like that if the user go inside VBA Editor, he can see it but without the windows inside it opened (as default)

I have used the code below but when I run macro nothing happens and, when I go to VBA Editor I continue to see opened the windows ... I don' t understand why ...

Thanks in advance !!!

```
Sub cc()

Dim wk, CodeWindow

For Each wk In Application.Workbooks
    If Not wk.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
       For Each CodeWindow In wk.VBProject.VBE.Windows
           If CodeWindow.Visible = True Then CodeWindow.Visible = False
       Next CodeWindow
    End If
Next wk

End Sub
```

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Comment: So you want all the open Workbooks to be closed? or you want to hide windows?

Comment: @TsiriniainaRakotonirina it is about the VBA-Editor code windows, not the worksheets.

Comment: The code will probably only work if the VBA Editor is open before you run it, because `CodeWindow.Visible` is only true if the Editor is open/visible. Also note that this code will also close the Project Explorer, Immediate Window, Property Window etc in the VBE. • So you can try if removeing `If CodeWindow.Visible = True Then` helps so `CodeWindow.Visible = False` will run in any case. That might work but I guess not (at least worth a try).

Comment: If you just want no VBA windows to be visible by default, close all VBA windows before you save the file (inside the VBA editor, don't just close the VBA editor itself). No code necessary. Excel remembers what code windows are opened when the file is saved.

Answer (score 2):

This , I think, is the Function you need to Close automatically all the open VBE Windows:

```
Public Sub CloseAllVBEWindows()
Dim wk As Workbook
Dim CodeWindow As Variant

'If VBE is closed the user shall allow it to open first
If Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False Then
    If MsgBox("VBE is still closed!" & vbCrLf & "The operation requires VBE to be open during its process. Would you like to open it?", vbInformation + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

'Then it will close all the windows
'Except the Default VBE Windows (Immediate Windows, Locals Windows ...)
For Each wk In Application.Workbooks
    If wk.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
       For Each CodeWindow In wk.VBProject.VBE.Windows
           If CodeWindow.Visible = True And CodeWindow.Type = 0 Then CodeWindow.Visible = False
       Next CodeWindow
    End If
Next wk

End Sub
```

You need to understand that in VBE even all the Panels are listed, so you shall close only the `CodeWindow.Type = 0` (Visual Basic Script Windows).

And it shall solve your issue! Just let me know

**Update:**
If VBE is closed the it will open VBE first and proceed to the Closing

Comment: The OP said *"when I run macro nothing happens"*. So if nothing happens that wasn't the issue. But anyway it is correct that he should check on `CodeWindow.Type = 0`. But I believe that hiding the windows only works if the editor is already open, because if it is closed none of the windows is `.Visible = True` therefore the `If` is never true and therefore none of the windows is ever set to `.Visible = False`.

Comment: @il_betto, I just updated the script to open the VBE first before proceeding. I agree with #PEH that the reason your script didn't work was may be VBE wasn't open. Thanks PEH

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot, a lot for the help !!

The macro, assembled like this, for me is good !!

```
Public Sub CloseAllVBEWindows()

Dim wk As Workbook
Dim CodeWindow As Variant

Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True

For Each wk In Application.Workbooks
    If wk.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
       For Each CodeWindow In wk.VBProject.VBE.Windows
           If CodeWindow.Visible = True Then CodeWindow.Visible = False
       Next CodeWindow
    End If
Next wk

End Sub
```

Fantastic !!

My problem was that as Option of Excel I have no put flag inside the last line of the image attached:
"trust access to the VBA project object model"[image]

Is there a way, with VBA code, to flag in automatic this Excel option ?

Thanks a lot again !!

Comment: No that is of course not possible, setting this trusting flag by code would be a security break as you can imagine. Any (malicious) code could extend its previleges to be trusted then.